"There Is" with Ellipsis in Negative Sentences
I came across the sentence: "There is no such thing as a bad memory, don't ever think there is. It's up to us.."
I understand the first part uses "there is" existentially, but I'm curious about the second part.  It seems to use ellipsis with "there is" at the end without a complete object.
Is this a grammatically correct construction?  How does ellipsis work in this context?

I'm a native speaker and I don't know what the second part is talking about. It's borderline gibberish.  Who knows what "it" refers to? Presumably the rest of the text goes on to explain?


There is no such thing as a bad memory, don't ever think there is.

Edit
Yes, there's an ellipsis at the imperative, and whichever applicable case has had its noun or noun phrase in square brackets omitted:

... don't ever think (that) there is [one].

or

... don't ever think (that) there is [such a thing].

The optional complementiser was also omitted.
The construction is grammatical although I would use a semicolon before don't.

"Don't ever think that there is [such a thing]", surely?

@KateBunting what do you think?

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  I have added your suggestion to my answer.
